# what is the latest and best face recognition algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, computer-vision

am doing my final project that includes face recognition and am trying to implement it on matlab. can anybody help me on getting some resources on each algorithms and their pro's and cons. plus if i get their matlab implementation i would be glad.

i've tried PCA(Eigenfaces) but in some resources it says it not a good algorithm anymore. so am looking for an alternative.

Comment: If you are looking for best face recognition algorithm, remember that it will require more efforts from your side. Anyway, searching Google Scholar should get you enough papers. I just found a PAMI paper: "Toward a practical face recognition system: Robust alignment and illumination by sparse representation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Viola Jones Face Detector is nice but of course it is just detection:
http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/425/slides/13-ViolaJones.pdf
if you want the best results you can try fusion by employing multiple methods at once and recogintion rate can increase considerably if performance is not an issue

Comment: ya i heared this is the fastest algorithm to detect faces but not for recognition.

Answer (score 3):

- One may use [Gabor wavelets](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vbettada/files/vinay-ProjectReport.pdf)
- face recognition in [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition)
- a [matlab code uses Gabor feature](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11073-face-detection-system)